# In Unity Game Modding, is there away to circumvent or substitute Resources.LoadAll?

Tags: unity, modding

I was playing a game recently and I started creating a mod to adjust it's gameplay to my liking, just for fun, until I got stressed out by how absurdly long the game takes to start up and show the main menu, so I fiddled around and found why it takes so long:

```
private void LoadResources()
  {
    this.allDropables.items = Resources.LoadAll("Items/Dropables", typeof (Transform)).Cast<Transform>().ToList<Transform>();
    this.allPotions.items = Resources.LoadAll("Items/Dropables/Potions", typeof (Transform)).Cast<Transform>().ToList<Transform>();
    this.allAmmos.items = Resources.LoadAll("Items/Dropables/Ammos", typeof (Transform)).Cast<Transform>().ToList<Transform>();
    this.allMiscs.items = Resources.LoadAll("Items/Dropables/Misc", typeof (Transform)).Cast<Transform>().ToList<Transform>();
    this.alllMinionScrolls.items = Resources.LoadAll("Items/Dropables/MinionScrolls", typeof (Transform)).Cast<Transform>().ToList<Transform>();
    this.allRings.items = Resources.LoadAll("Items/Dropables/Rings", typeof (Transform)).Cast<Transform>().ToList<Transform>();
    this.allArmors.items = Resources.LoadAll("Items/Dropables/Armors", typeof (Transform)).Cast<Transform>().ToList<Transform>();
    this.allNecklaces.items = Resources.LoadAll("Items/Dropables/Necklaces", typeof (Transform)).Cast<Transform>().ToList<Transform>();
    this.allWeapons.items = Resources.LoadAll("Items/Dropables/Weapons", typeof (Transform)).Cast<Transform>().ToList<Transform>();
    this.allTreasures.items = Resources.LoadAll("Items/Dropables/Treasures", typeof (Transform)).Cast<Transform>().ToList<Transform>();
    this.allBlackmarketItems.items = Resources.LoadAll("Items/RareItems/Blackmarket", typeof (Transform)).Cast<Transform>().ToList<Transform>();
    this.allItems.items = Resources.LoadAll("Items", typeof (Transform)).Cast<Transform>().ToList<Transform>();
    this.allCollections.items = Resources.LoadAll("Items/Collections", typeof (Transform)).Cast<Transform>().ToList<Transform>();
    this.allTreasureChests.items = Resources.LoadAll("TreasureChests", typeof (Transform)).Cast<Transform>().ToList<Transform>();
    this.allCompanions.items = Resources.LoadAll("Companions", typeof (Transform)).Cast<Transform>().ToList<Transform>();
    this.allMinions.items = Resources.LoadAll("Minions", typeof (Transform)).Cast<Transform>().ToList<Transform>();
    this.allAchievements.items = Resources.LoadAll("Achievements", typeof (Transform)).Cast<Transform>().ToList<Transform>();
    this.allFreePoses.items = Resources.LoadAll("Poses", typeof (Transform)).Cast<Transform>().ToList<Transform>();
    this.allBuildings.items = Resources.LoadAll("Buildings", typeof (Transform)).Cast<Transform>().ToList<Transform>();
    this.allFieldArmies.items = Resources.LoadAll("Field Armies", typeof (Transform)).Cast<Transform>().ToList<Transform>();
    this.allLingeries.items = Resources.LoadAll("Items/RareItems/Lingeries", typeof (Transform)).Cast<Transform>().ToList<Transform>();
    this.allAffixes.items = Resources.LoadAll("Affixes", typeof (Transform)).Cast<Transform>().ToList<Transform>();
    this.weaponPrefixes.items = Resources.LoadAll("Affixes/Weapons/Prefixes", typeof (Transform)).Cast<Transform>().ToList<Transform>();
    this.weaponSurfixes.items = Resources.LoadAll("Affixes/Weapons/Surfixes", typeof (Transform)).Cast<Transform>().ToList<Transform>();
    this.armorPrefixes.items = Resources.LoadAll("Affixes/Armors/Prefixes", typeof (Transform)).Cast<Transform>().ToList<Transform>();
    this.armorSurfixes.items = Resources.LoadAll("Affixes/Armors/Surfixes", typeof (Transform)).Cast<Transform>().ToList<Transform>();
    // . . . A whole lot more of LoadAll calls and some for loops
```

In BepInEx with Harmony Patch I can simply make the game skip invoking this function and the menu opens really fast, and the game "mostly" works. Needless to say, some things don't work as intended.
So the first thing I thought to myself and decided to do was convert these HUGE blocks of blocking `LoadAll` calls with smaller Tasks running all of this loading in parallel, so I isolated and successfully implemented loading `allCollections.items` in a Task and made the code that actually uses it wait for that task to finish loading and it worked GOOD, but most of the other things crash the game if they're LoadAll'ed from a task;

So, my question here is: Is there a way to get a list of resource paths from these path-bases, so that I can substitute these one-time "LoadAll" with smaller on-demand "Load" calls, or is there anything that I could do to modify this game into not taking an eternity to start?

Edit: Further things that I discovered:

`Resources.LoadAll` refuses to be called from a thread that is not the main thread, it is the cause for the crash. It doesn't throw an exception, it's impossible to catch the error `LoadAll` causes by normal means. Some of the lists work because Tasks don't always run on another thread. The problem obviously is that the rendering and all other stuff happens on that same main thread too.

There is `LoadAsync` and though it allows for an "empty path" argument for "Load absolutely everything", it is unable to load resources from a subfolder in the same way that `LoadAll` does. When passing a general folder to `LoadAsync` I get a `ResourceRequest` that's always imediately `isDone=true` and `asset=null`. It's not documented what that means, but I'm assumign "Not Found", also doing `LoadAsync("")` freezes the game as if calling `LoadAll`

I fiddled a lot with this so far and it would be easy if I could query the UnityEngine like "Give me all resource paths starting with  path", but the engine does not have that function either

Comment: This is an optimization you should really leave to the original developers of the game. They might have a reason why they want to load all their resources on game start and not do on-demand loading. And parallelization of file read operations usually doesn't have much benefit, because the bottleneck is usually the drive, not the CPU. Requesting many files at once makes the performance of many drives worse instead of better.